# Listing products together with prices and dropdowns. ListView vs LinearLayout? Or what else?

Tags: android, listview, row, spinner, android-linearlayout

I would like to create a list of products within my app, with a picture on the left and a dimension dropdown on the right. Users would pick a size for each product and then in the next activity they would see the order with the total price and the products they want (like a shopping cart).

For two days I am wrestling with a custom ListView and array adapter, but as I solve a problem regarding the recycling of the rows while scrolling, another problem arises **like as the quantity boxes reset to "0" as they got outside the visible area of the screen.**

I think the ListView is not the right solution for a product display, with quantity boxes and dropdown windows on each row.

Should I create the rows dynamically in LinearLayouts and tag each dropdown and quantity box so I can get their values on checkout?

What would be the right solution?

Thanks!

The way I extract the values of the dropdowns and quantity boxes:

```
displayOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {  

                int numOfPhotos = PhotosListAdapter.getCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfPhotos; i++) {

                //System.out.println(PhotosListAdapter.getItemId(i));
                View view = PhotosListView.getChildAt(i);

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.photo_format);
                EditText tv = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

                System.out.println(tv.getText() + " " + spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
```

And my custom ArrayAdapter:

```
Public class PhotosListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItemsSetter> {

        DeleteImageListener dListener;
        private Context context;
        private int layoutResourceId;
        private ArrayList<ImageItemsSetter> data = new ArrayList<ImageItemsSetter>();       


        //standard constructor
        public PhotosListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageItemsSetter> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }           

        static class ViewHolder {

            public ImageView Img; 
            public Spinner spinner;
            public Button delete;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            ImageItemsSetter image = data.get(position);

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(); 

            holder.Img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.Img);
            holder.spinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_format);
            holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteImage);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }   



        holder.Img.setImageBitmap(image.getTheImage());              

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                R.array.formats_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
        holder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //The delete button
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           

                if (dListener != null) {  
                    dListener.onDeletePressed(position); 
                }       
            }           
            });

        return row;
        }


        //Interface to send selected image's position for deletion
        public void setDeleteImageListener(DeleteImageListener listener) {  
            this.dListener = listener;  
        } 

        public static interface DeleteImageListener { 
            public void onDeletePressed(int position);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy Try this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;


    ImageItemsSetter image = data.get(position);


    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);


    ImageView Img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.Img);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_format);
    Button delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteImage);




Img.setImageBitmap(image.getTheImage());              

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
        R.array.formats_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

//The delete button
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {           

        if (dListener != null) {  
            dListener.onDeletePressed(position); 
        }       
    }           
    });

return row;
}
```

Comment: Same problem. I think I will have to save somehow all the input fields before they get out of the visible area. :(